# Converting a string of numbers into a 2d array

Tags: java

Hello I have a file of information in the format of

5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa

Each row contains 4 numbers and one string with a total of 75 rows. I am attempting to save the numbers into a 2D array, and then the string into its own 1D array. But I am having trouble converting from the string array I have into a 2D array of double value

```
...
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NearestNeighbor {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    
    //creates empty values for our arrays
    double [][] testingVal= new double[75][4]; 
    double[][] trainingVal= new double[75][4];
    String [] trainingClassLabel = new String [75];
    String [] testingClassLabel = new String [75];
    
    //User inputs for file names
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the name of the training file: ");
    String training=input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the name of the testing file: ");
    String testing=input.nextLine();
    
    //creates array for our training values
    File trainingFile = new File(training);
    Scanner fileScanTraining = new Scanner(trainingFile);
    for (int i = 1; fileScanTraining.hasNext(); i++) {
        String line = fileScanTraining.nextLine();
        trainingVal=line.split(",",4);
        System.out.println(line); 
    }
    
    
    //creates array for our testing values
    File testingFile = new File(testing);
    Scanner fileScanTesting = new Scanner(trainingFile);
    //Finally we close our scanners
    fileScanTraining.close();
    fileScanTesting.close();
    input.close();
  }


  }

 ...
```

Comment: "[H]aving trouble" covers a lot of ground.  Can you be more precise about what kind of trouble you're having?

Comment: Converting my string array into a 2D array. I don't know what middle step I need to be able to do this

Comment: HINTS: `String[] data = line.split(",");` and (in a nested for loop) `testingVal[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(data[j]);`. Does that help any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make a couple of changes in the loop where you read the contents of `trainingFile`.

```java
Scanner fileScanTraining = new Scanner(trainingFile);
for (int i = 1; fileScanTraining.hasNextLine(); i++) { // changed this line
    String line = fileScanTraining.nextLine();
    String[] numbers = line.split(",", 4); // added this line
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) { // added this loop
        trainingVal[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(numbers[j]);
    }
    System.out.println(line); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple looping can be used like below -

```
    int i=0;
    while (fileScanTraining.hasNext()){
        String line = fileScanTraining.nextLine();
        String[] splittedVal=line.split(",");
        int j=0;
        while(j< 4){
            testingVal[i][j]=Double.parseDouble(splittedVal[j]);
            j++;

        }
    i++;
    }
```